# open excel file on sheet1 after changes with xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I need an Excel workbook to open on sheet1 or by that sheets name. I'm using xlwings to alter a workbook with several sheets. Everything works fine but when the file is opened in Excel it opens on the last sheet that has been altered. I can't seem to find an answer. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is what might help you

```
# load Workbook
workbook= xw.Book('path_file')

#acivate sheet by name
sheet = workbook.sheets.activate('Sheet_Name')
```

## if that doesn't work try

```
sheet = workbook.sheets["Sheet_Name"]
```